# How persist new created parent and child entities with hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, parent-child, spring-data-rest

Here is entities:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent" ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Collection<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Parent parent;

}
```

For managing this entities I use spring data (rest). I need to save entities like that:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child = new Child()
parent.setChildren(Arrays.asList(child))
springDataRepository.save(parent);
```

And only Parent object is persisted.

Also as I spot `parent` and `child` are created without `id`. So should I persist only `parent`, then set it to `child` and persist `child`? Can these operation be done with one `parent` saving action?

Answer (score 1):

See this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7428143

Instead of:

```
parent.setChildren(Arrays.asList(child))
```

you should use:

```
parent.setChildren(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(child)))
```