# Unidirectional @OneToOne resulting in null foreign key

Tags: spring, hibernate, entity, relationship, one-to-one

I have two entities:

`User.java`

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @NotBlank
    String username;
    @NotBlank
    String password;

    @ElementCollection
    @Builder.Default
    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`Student.java`

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Student {
    @Id
    String id;
    String name;
    String firstName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User user;

    public void addUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

The `StudentService` should add a new `Student`, create a new `User` and add it to the `Student`

```
@Override
public boolean addStudent(StudentDTO student) {
    if (!studentRepository.existsById(student.getId())) {
        Student s = modelMapper.map(student, Student.class);
        studentRepository.save(s);

        String username = String.format("s%s", student.getId());
        List<String> roles = Arrays.asList("ROLE_STUDENT");
        User user = userService.createUser(username, roles);
        userService.addUser(user);
        s.addUser(user);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `User` is being created by `UserService`

```
@Override
public User createUser(String username, List<String> roles) {
    String password = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(16);
    User u = User.builder()
            .username(username)
            .password(encoder.encode(password))
            .roles(roles)
            .build();
    if (addUser(u)) {
        return u;
    } else {
        throw new UserAlreadyExistingException(username);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean addUser(User user) {
    boolean alreadyExists = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).isPresent();
    if (true) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Despite the `User` and the `Student` are being added to my database, the `user_id` column in the `student` table is always set to null. I also checked if the `User` being added to the `Student` is properly initialized and filled with all the information but the transaction is committed.

Answer (score 1):

`user_id` is set to null because you are not saving mapping to database.
Changed code with comments:

```java
@Override
public boolean addStudent(StudentDTO student) {
    if (!studentRepository.existsById(student.getId())) {
        Student s = modelMapper.map(student, Student.class);
     // don't save student here

        String username = String.format("s%s", student.getId());
        List<String> roles = Arrays.asList("ROLE_STUDENT");
        User user = userService.createUser(username, roles);
        userService.addUser(user);
        s.addUser(user);
        //save student here after adding user. 
        studentRepository.save(s)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: yes, that was it, but if I add ``cascade = CascadeType.ALL`` to the ``@OneToOne`` annotation in the ``Student`` class, when I try to add a new student it throws a ``java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException``, why?

Comment: for `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`, check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7428143/7505731

Comment: The ``Arrays.asList()`` isn't the curlprit I guess, I tried to not save the ``User`` before the ``Student``, so the ``User`` is added to the ``Student`` and then they will both be saved in one transaction. In this case the ``cascade = CascadeType.ALL`` seems to work. Do you know why?

Comment: not able to figure out. did it work or still an issue ?

Comment: I solved by adding the ``User`` and ``Student`` into one transaction.