# String boot update java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null

Tags: spring-boot

I get an error when using the save(update) Function while adding with is working properly.

1.ProductService:

```
    @Override
        public ProductDTO save(ProductDTO product) {
            ProductEntity entity= null;
            if(product.getId()!=null)
            {
                ProductEntity oldProduct= productrepository.findById(product.getId()).get();
                entity=converter.toEntity(product, oldProduct);
            }else {
                entity= converter.modelMapper().map(product, ProductEntity.class);
            }
            entity.setCategory(categoryRepository.findById(product.getCategoryId()).get());
            entity.setOrigins(toList(originRepository.findById(product.getOriginId())));
            entity.setMaterials(toList(materialRepository.findById(product.getMaterialId())));
            entity.setType(typeRepository.findById(product.getTypeId()).get());
            productrepository.save(entity);
            return converter.modelMapper().map(entity, ProductDTO.class);
        }
```

2. add product & update:

```
    @PostMapping(value="/product")
        public ProductDTO addProduct(@ModelAttribute ProductDTO model)
        {
            return iProductService.save(model);
        }
    @PutMapping(value="/product")
        public ProductDTO editProduct(@ModelAttribute ProductDTO model)
        {
            return iProductService.save(model);
        }
```

- When I add the product it works properly, but when I update the product it throws an error:

```
    2022-09-08 20:19:40.892 ERROR 14524 --- [nio-8081-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException] with root cause
    
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:167) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:387) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.removeRange(AbstractList.java:598) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.clear(AbstractList.java:243) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:580) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:757) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:829) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:816) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.7.Final.jar:5.6.7.Final]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at jdk.proxy25/jdk.proxy25.$Proxy348.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at jdk.proxy25/jdk.proxy25.$Proxy348.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:640) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
        at jdk.proxy25/jdk.proxy25.$Proxy350.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.lifood.stuneed.service.impl.ProductService.save(ProductService.java:81) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.lifood.stuneed.api.ProductAPI.addProduct(ProductAPI.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
```

when I comment the save function save
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkR3Q.png)

product id exists but it still gives error, I am using.
java: 17
spring-framework: 5.3.18

Comment: Maybe something to do with attempting to make changes to an unmodifiable list. This also maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428089/unsupportedoperationexception-merge-saving-many-to-many-relation-with-hibernate

Comment: Also productrepository.save(entity); returns the saved entity so you should be using that to map to your DTO